# the method `into_iter` exists for struct `String`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

Tags: rust

I wan't to concat name which is String with online_presence and requestor but I got this issue.

```
let concat: Vec<u8> = name
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .chain(online_presence.unwrap())
        .chain(requestor.to_keyed_vec(Default::default()))
        .chain(Self::env().block_timestamp().to_be_bytes())
        .collect();
```

[image]

```
error[E0599]: the method `into_iter` exists for struct `String`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> /Users/ganesholi/Developer/me-protocol/rusty-protocol-v0.1/contracts/providers/services/brands.rs:63:14
    |
61  |           let concat: Vec<u8> = name
    |  _______________________________-
62  | |             .unwrap()
63  | |             .into_iter()
```

Can somebody suggest do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please paste directly you problematic code and **whole** error message.

Comment: What do you want to do anyway? If you want to iterate over string's characters use method [String::chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars).

Comment: I wan't to concat name which is String with online_presence and requestor but I got this issue. @AleksanderKrauze

Comment: Use `String::as_bytes` and then iterate over it

Answer (score 4):

Sounds a bit like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

If I understand correctly, what you really want to do seems to be to concat multiple strings together without occurring unnecessary allocations.

You'll at least need one allocation, at which point you can just [format!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html). You can also use [write!](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/fn.write.html) to pre-allocate a buffer.

```rust
let concat = format!("{}{}{}{}", name, online_presence.unwrap(), requestor.to_keyed_vec(Default::default()), Self::env().block_timestamp());
```

If you don't want a string, but instead want to chain together certain byte sequences use [String::into_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_bytes) and call `into_iter` + `chain` on that:

```rust
let concat = name.into_bytes().into_iter()
    .chain(online_presence.unwrap()) // assuming this already is an iter over bytes
    .chain(requestor.to_keyed_vec(Default::default())) // assuming this already is an iter over bytes
    .chain(Self::env().block_timestamp().to_be_bytes())
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```